# Change url parameter value after page loaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

What I would like to accomplish is to load the specific page id's, after loading, it should load the next page. I am using an iframe to load a page with specific `id` from URL parameter. This is to update changes that has been done to the selected page.

> www.sample.com/page?page_id=`page-id-here`

What I did so far was to put all the specific `page id's` into array so that I can easily load the next page through the array index.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 17
    [1] => 28
    [2] => 73
    [3] => 85
    [4] => 111
    [5] => 147
    [6] => 154
    [7] => 181
    [8] => 207
    [9] => 229
    [10] => 248
    [11] => 250
    [12] => 255
}
```

Array is in `$data` variable.

```
<script>
var counter = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("iframe#iframeloader").load(function(){

        counter = counter + 1
        var number = <?= $data.'['?> counter <? echo ']';?>
        if(counter==2) window.location.href = "/page?page_id=<?=$number?>";
    });
});


</script>

<iframe id="iframeloader" src="/page?page_id=<?=$data?>" style="width:100%; height:1000px"></iframe>
```

I am a bit confused how to make this work. The iframe could not get the page source.

Comment: This looks strange. Wouldn't this page load an iframe that loads itself, that loads an iframe that loads itself that loads an iframe that loads itself and so on?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson What should be the right approach here?

Comment: I actually don't really understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: This looks wrong as well: `<?= $data.'['?> counter <? echo ']';?>`. What do you expect that to output?

Comment: What I am trying to do is to load the specific pages. To update the amendments that  has been done. Each page have code to update data to database.

Comment: `<?= $data.'['?> counter <? echo ']';?>` My bad, thinking that this will get the next value of array index e.g `$data[0]` which is equal to page_id `17`  to `$data[1]` and so on..

Comment: You can't mix PHP and JS like that. PHP gets executed on the _server_. The result will then be sent to the client where the JS get's executed. Is `$data` an array? Then you can't echo it, like you're doing in the iframe src. You should get some error (Array to string conversion) and your `<?= $data ?>` in the iframe should just produce `?page_id=Array` or something.